# laravel-5 routing after email activation

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5. I am trying to authenticate new users via email. The emailing process works but I am getting a routing problem

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:

after clicking the url in the email. 
The url mySite/activate/ltQ92fhDRPrRBZKipwEWJ4a1HaUcPZKcgZZlt3IWxkhHmvGbaOfjpBhplU5M  is correct.

My route is

```
Route::get('activate/{$activation_code}', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

Comment: Your route parameter is prefixed with a $ sign. This could be the problem. Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `$` for assigning variables in route parameters, try this:

```
Route::get('activate/{activation_code}', 'WelcomeController@index');
```